# unix script for finding multiple words with a value, then remove lines that don't match

Tags: regex, bash, sorting, grep

Lets say I have several files containing this:

```
[srv] $ cat *.file.* | egrep -R -h -A 3 'is up'

interface0/1, is up
0 input errors, 18 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
0 output errors, 7299 collisions, 0 interface resets
--
interface0/2, is up
0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
--
interface0/5, is up
669 input errors, 192 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
0 output errors, 4991 collisions, 0 interface resets
--
.
.
n..
interface0/n, is up
0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
--
```

I want to print out any interface with counter value > 0 and that "is up", except interface resets . 
When I use grep, I wont get to se what interface that the line belongs to :/

Is it possible to gather out the lines that match my criteria?

Comment: can you post a few lines of one of the `*.file.*` ?

Comment: @Kemosabe That `n` in `interface0/n, is up` is the counter right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the file that holds the lines, you could just use pass the arguments directly to egrep instead ad use `-H` not `-h`:

```
egrep -R -H -A 3 'is up' *.file.*
```

UPDATE: You can try this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

/^interface[0-9]+\/[0-9]+, is up/ {
    split($0, a, /[,\/]/)
    if (a[2] > 0) {
        getline b
        getline c
        if (c ~ /0 interface resets$/) {
            printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n--\n", $0, b, c
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `awk -f script.awk *.file.*`

Example output:

```
interface0/1, is up
0 input errors, 18 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
0 output errors, 7299 collisions, 0 interface resets
--
interface0/2, is up
0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
--
interface0/5, is up
669 input errors, 192 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
0 output errors, 4991 collisions, 0 interface resets
--
```

Comment: I will certainly try this. I'l try it out in a sec

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

`sed -n -e '/is up/ {;N;N;/is up.*[1-9].* 0 interface resets/p;}' *.file.*`